# search in mysql with utf8 encoding

Tags: php, mysql, search, utf-8

im working on a project in Arabic language
i need to search in database of utf-8 words the table Collation in ' utf8' and MySQL connection type is utf8 too.

now when i type the word (for example 'ﺗﻮﺿﻴﺢ') in my query string with my keyboard it cant find some of the results BUT when i try to copy and paste from phpmyadmin i find all of the results!!

image 1 shown the result when i will type by my keyborad
[image: image 1 shown the result when i will type by my keyborad]

and image 2 shown the result in same database when i will copy and paste the search term

[image: result in same database when i will copy and paste the search term]

question is what is the problem and how can i type to search term to find all of the results...

PS:
1)i have to attache both post content first is for copy and paste text and second is for when i will typing the text

i found this differentiation between my post queries

when i copy the text :

```
is_js_confirmed=0&db=digidoc&table=docs_pages&token=43847946c2deb1885e9c0f9ed97839a3&pos=0&goto=tbl_sql.php&message_to_show=Your+SQL+query+has+been+executed+successfully&prev_sql_query=SELECT+*+FROM+%60docs_pages%60+WHERE+%60page_content%60+LIKE+'%25%EF%BA%97%EF%BB%AE%EF%BA%BF%EF%BB%B4%EF%BA%A2%25'&sql_query=SELECT+*+FROM+%60docs_pages%60+WHERE+%60page_content%60+LIKE+'%25%EF%BA%97%EF%BB%AE%EF%BA%BF%EF%BB%B4%EF%BA%A2%25'&bkm_label=&sql_delimiter=%3B&show_query=1&ajax_request=true
```

and when i will type it :

```
is_js_confirmed=0&db=digidoc&table=docs_pages&token=43847946c2deb1885e9c0f9ed97839a3&pos=0&goto=tbl_sql.php&message_to_show=Your+SQL+query+has+been+executed+successfully&prev_sql_query=SELECT+*+FROM+%60docs_pages%60+WHERE+%60page_content%60+like+'%25%2525%25EF%25BA%2597%25EF%25BB%25AE%25EF%25BA%25BF%25EF%25BB%25B4%25EF%25BA%25A2%2525%25'&sql_query=SELECT+*+FROM+%60docs_pages%60+WHERE+%60page_content%60+like+'%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%B6%DB%8C%D8%AD'&bkm_label=&sql_delimiter=%3B&show_query=1&ajax_request=true
```

but why!? the same chars in same browser!

Comment: Check request contents with browser's network console (F12).
There might be some difference, like encoding your chars differently.
Make sure that your browser's page encoding is UTF-8 when you type via keyboard

Comment: By "query string" do you mean a part of URL called query string, or is the variable passed using POST?

Comment: @Qwerty : main question has been updated and the browser page encoding is utf8

Comment: @lafor : query string mean the query i will run in sql tab in phpmyadmin and as my update you can see the post body is contain the same search terms...

Comment: is this problem depend on the fonts of saved text and my browser fonts !?!!!!